# How do I add timestamps to individual lines of PowerShell & output?

Tags: datetime, powershell, logging, process

How, if at all, is it possible to add timestamps to each line of an output generated by the `&` PowerShell operator?

Example:

```
PS H:\> $result = & ping 192.168.1.1
PS H:\> echo $result

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=250
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=250
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=250
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=250
Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 102ms, Maximum = 106ms, Average = 103ms
```

Desired result:

```
PS H:\> echo $result

2014-12-08T14:45:48.8898125+00:00:Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
2014-12-08T14:45:48.8932661+00:00:Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=250
2014-12-08T14:45:48.9233451+00:00:Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=106ms TTL=250
2014-12-08T14:45:48.9765438+00:00:Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=250
2014-12-08T14:45:49.0233105+00:00:Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=250
2014-12-08T14:45:49.0233201+00:00:
2014-12-08T14:45:49.0238753+00:00:Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
2014-12-08T14:45:49.0239210+00:00:    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
2014-12-08T14:45:49.0233318+00:00:Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
2014-12-08T14:45:49.0237209+00:00:    Minimum = 102ms, Maximum = 106ms, Average = 103ms
```

I know how to split / join a PowerShell array, but this can only happen AFTER the `&` operator completes. I am looking for more realtime-like solution, where timestamps are added to the output while the & operator is running.

By the way, the timestamp itself is `$($(Get-Date -Format o) + ":")`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use a filter:

```
filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format o): $_"}
$result = & ping 192.168.1.1 | timestamp
```

Sample output from `$result`:

```
2014-12-08T11:42:59.2827202-05:00: 
2014-12-08T11:42:59.2857205-05:00: Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
2014-12-08T11:43:03.1241043-05:00: Request timed out.
2014-12-08T11:43:08.1236042-05:00: Request timed out.
2014-12-08T11:43:13.1241042-05:00: Request timed out.
2014-12-08T11:43:18.1246042-05:00: Request timed out.
2014-12-08T11:43:18.1246042-05:00: 
2014-12-08T11:43:18.1246042-05:00: Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
2014-12-08T11:43:18.1246042-05:00:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: My question was about how to add timestamps to the output in the first place, not how to filter them in (or out) subsequently.

Comment: That's what the filter is doing.  A PowerShell filter is a script block that accepts input from the pipeline, and runs once for each object that it gets from the pipeline. It's functionally the same as a function with only a Process block.  That filter will add the timestamp to each line output from your executable.

Comment: Ahh, indeed, it DOES work exactly as you described. Thanks a million - problem solved!

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It opens a whole new world to me as I learned how to define my own output filters. 

Answer (score 14):

For anyone that is looking for more information on `filter`, [here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6#filters).  It was surprising difficult to find since searching any combination of the word "filter" and "powershell" will give a million examples and no documentation.  Also `help filter` in powershell provides no obvious help either.

The answer provided by mjolinor is the best way to do something like this, but I wanted to expand on it.

```
filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date): $_"}
```

Is a shortcut for calling this

```
function timestamp { Process{"$(Get-Date): $_"} }
```

Both of these create named functions that accept input from the pipeline.  Run `help pipline` in powershell to learn more.  The pipeline will operate on a single object at a time, and that object can be referred to with the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) `$_`.  So each function will iterate over every item in the pipeline that was piped to it using the `|` pipe character.

This behaves differently than a normal function in that it's working on the objects as they arrive, instead of all at once.  For example running

```
function timestamp {
        "$(Get-Date): $input"
}
$result = & ping 127.0.0.1
$result | timestamp
```

Would dump the entire `$result` object on a single line and result in a response that looks like this

```
03/14/2018 15:23:16:  Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 127.0.0.1: b
ytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 12
7.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128  Pi
ng statistics for 127.0.0.1:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), 
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Avera
ge = 0ms
```

Since the function is operating on the object as a whole you would have to iterate over each line.  Changing it to this

```
function timestampfunction {
    foreach ($i in $input){
        "$(Get-Date): $i"
    }
}
```

Would give you the nicely formatted

```
03/14/2018 15:23:16: 
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
03/14/2018 15:23:16: 
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
03/14/2018 15:23:16:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
03/14/2018 15:23:16: Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
03/14/2018 15:23:16:     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

[Here](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-filter-2/) is a nicely written article on the differences between these approaches.

Answer (score 10):

You can just use `ForEach-Object` cmdlet for it (used `%` alias in below example)

```
ping 192.168.1.1 | %{ "{0:HH:mm:ss:fff}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), $_ }
```

result:

```
23:41:51:301:
23:41:51:302: Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
23:41:55:255: Request timed out.
23:42:00:266: Request timed out.
23:42:05:254: Request timed out.
23:42:10:253: Request timed out.
23:42:10:261:
23:42:10:263: Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
23:42:10:265:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Or use format like in mjolinor answer:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 | %{ "{0:o}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), $_ }
```

result:

```
2019-04-23T23:45:40.5816185+02:00:
2019-04-23T23:45:40.5845856+02:00: Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
2019-04-23T23:45:44.2560567+02:00: Request timed out.
2019-04-23T23:45:49.2549104+02:00: Request timed out.
2019-04-23T23:45:54.2547535+02:00: Request timed out.
2019-04-23T23:45:59.2547932+02:00: Request timed out.
2019-04-23T23:45:59.2577788+02:00:
2019-04-23T23:45:59.2607707+02:00: Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
2019-04-23T23:45:59.2627647+02:00:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: This is likely the shortest possible code to get things working, well done. I am sticking with mjolinor's solution though as it suits me better (larger code base, multiple scripts etc so code re-usability is important to me)

Comment: While not perfect, variation of this worked for my usage case. I was getting `ComObject` in mjolinor example.
I'm using this now:
```Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot | %{(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss), $_} | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdateLog.txt -Append```

Comment: In case someone else has similar usage case, where you're trying to log output of another PowerShell command, such as `Test-Connection` or like me installing WinUpdate, this is what you need to do. Example for update commandlet logging: `Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll |  %{ "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), "X: "+$_.X+" ; Result: "+$_.Result+" ; KB: "+$_.KB+" ; Size: "+$_.Size+" , Title: "+$_.Title }  | Out-File "APingLog.txt" -Append`

Comment: And example for "ping" would be `Test-Connection -Ping -IPv4 -Count 8 -TargetName www.google.com | %{ "{0:HH:mm:ss:fff}: {1}" -f (Get-Date), "Testing IP : " + $_.Address + " ; Latency is " + $_.Latency + " ms ; Status is : " + $_.Status }`. Output example : `15:31:36:815: Testing IP : 142.250.186.36 ; Latency is 41 ms ; Status is : Success` (If you want logging to file add same ` | Out-File SomePingLog.txt -Append` to end of command

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Start-Transcript cmdlet in combination with a custom prompt in your profile:

```
# Configure PS prompt to show date and time
function prompt
{ 
    $promptStringStart = "PS:" + (Get-Date -format MM/dd/yy` hh:mm:ss)
    $promptStringEnd += ">"
    Write-Host $promptStringStart -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host $promptStringEnd -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    return " "
}
```

This works great on my Windows 7 workstation. However, on some newer Server 2012 R2 installations Start-Transcript seems to be slightly broken. This fixes part of it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3014136/powershell-transcript-file-doesn-t-contain-the-correct-information-in-windows-server-2012-r2

... but it does not fix the issue with the custom prompt, still.

For example, I see this on the console:

```
PS:02/14/17 08:28:20> hostname
server463
```

And this is what's written to the log:

```
PS:02/14/17 08:28:20
>

PS>hostname
server463
```

Comment: Thank you, this is quite an interesting approach and I'm sure it is useful in certain scenarios. I am sticking with the timestamp filter approach though as per mjolinor's answer above. Suits my needs better.