# Adding Timestamp to Postgres PSQL execution output via Powershell Start-Transcript

Tags: postgresql, powershell, timestamp, output, psql

I have searched the foruns and the web, and I did not find any situation that matches my problem.

I need to "take an action" based in the verbose output of an PSQL command (postgres line comand), from a Powershell execution.

The best I could find (with lots of thanks to people from stack exchange) is to register the verbose using Start-Transcript, and then to read the log and take the actions. The thing is, there I still need to check if there is a way to take an action "during" the execution, or **at least** to "measure time" of each verbose output.

Very unfortunately I cannot alter the pgsql functions right, all I have is the verbose output and the "notices" that are already implemented.

I tried the "filter timestamp" solution suggested by "[How do I add timestamps to individual lines of PowerShell & output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361452/how-do-i-add-timestamps-to-individual-lines-of-powershell-output)", but for some reason it's not generating the timestamp the way I need.

I did exactly as the post example, as you can see my very simple powershell commands are:

```
filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format o): $_"}
cmd /c $DBCmd -f c:\di\mycmd.sql "postgresql://myuser:mypass@myhost/mydb" | timestamp
```

The results when checking the Start-Transcript generated log as well as directly in the command line, are as follow:

```
2018-07-30T16:30:32.6632687-03:00:              ?column?
2018-07-30T16:30:32.6632687-03:00: -----------------------------------
2018-07-30T16:30:32.6632687-03:00:  TIME2018-07-30 16:26:09.683957-03
2018-07-30T16:30:32.6632687-03:00: (1 row)
2018-07-30T16:30:32.6789028-03:00:
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NFC_NECF_RDIA_ANALIT_ITEM]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NFC_NECF_NF]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NFC_NECF_RDIA_ANALIT]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NF_ITEM]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_CFE_EQP_SAT]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NFC_ECF_CFE_CPL]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_CFE]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NFC_NECF_NF_ITEM]
psql:c:/di/LOCK01.sql:2: NOTICE:  [LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_NF_CPL]
2018-07-30T16:30:37.2569238-03:00:  fn_adt_myfunction
2018-07-30T16:30:37.2588785-03:00: -----------------------------------------
2018-07-30T16:30:37.2598554-03:00:                                        1
2018-07-30T16:30:37.2608365-03:00: (1 row)
2018-07-30T16:30:37.2618073-03:00:
```

The commad mycmd.sql is the execution of a pgsql function:

```
SELECT adt_objprog.fn_myfunction(myparams);
```

The function myfunction have simple Deletes, as shown:

```
v_cmd := 'DELETE FROM ADT_TDL.ADT_SPD_EFD_EGA_CV115_CDIA_ANALIT'||v_partionname||' WHERE COD_INT_ADT = '||v_cod_int_adt||' AND COD_INT_EFD IN (SELECT COD_INT_EFD FROM WORKDL_ADT.ADT_SPD_EFD_CHAVE_REMOCAO_1427_1);';
raise notice '[LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_EGA_CV115_CDIA_ANALIT]';
execute(v_cmd);
v_cmd := 'DELETE FROM ADT_TDL.ADT_SPD_EFD_EGA_CV115_CDIA'||v_partionname||' WHERE COD_INT_ADT = '||v_cod_int_adt||' AND COD_INT_EFD IN (SELECT COD_INT_EFD FROM WORKDL_ADT.ADT_SPD_EFD_CHAVE_REMOCAO_1427_1);';
raise notice '[LOG][Delete] [ADT_SPD_EFD_EGA_CV115_CDIA]';
execute(v_cmd);
```

I don't really understand why the timestamp is not being generated for the "notice" messages, as you can see in the example.

Does anyone have a clue about why this is happening, and if there is a way (any way) to do this?

Thank you very much in advance,

Best regards,

Luiz

ps: I did change the Title to a better one (I think), and minor corrections.

Comment: Since you need to run it from the command line, have you tried to create a bash script? also, if what you need is the execution time, have you checked pg_stat_activity?

Comment: Hello Dan, A bash script is not an option, due to project conditions, we need to use PowerShell. Pg_stat_activity could give me this information, with a little loss in accuracy, but it would trigger other problems with DBAs and stuff, but I will keep that in mind. Right now i'm still hoping that I will be able to set the timestamp for the notice message. For instance I was thinking in a solution: When Start-Transcript write the notice message to the log file, I will keep another instance "tailing" the log file, and them re-writing the messages properly with timestamp, something like that. TKS!